# HTA / VBScript /accdb: trouble with getting multiple rows from db

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, hta

I am currently working on a function to get some values from my access database into some columns (called "slots" in my code).

problem exists in the function fillSlot(), the SQL queries are executed by the function dbCall()

while I was trying to create the output Flakes asked for I changed my code like this and it does at least something now. Used functions: dbCall to get Data from my db, fillSlot to use that data, createSlots to create the slots and call fillSlot once per Slot.

```
function dbCall(dbQuery, iAmount)
    
    Dim sConnectionString, objConnection, objRecordset, lTemp
    
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & localDB
    objCommand.ActiveConnection = sConnectionString
    
    'do DB-Stuff
    objCommand.CommandText = dbQuery
    objCommand.CommandType = 1
    set objRecordset = objCommand.Execute
    Select Case iAmount
        Case -1
            'unknown amount of results
            set lTemp = objRecordset.fields
            set dbCall = lTemp
        Case 0
            'zero results - for update-queries
            dbCall = 0
        Case 1
            'exactly one result
            lTemp = objRecordset.fields(0)
        
            dbCall = lTemp
    End Select
End function

function fillSlot(iSlot)
    Dim lUsers, oSlot, iCount, tid, tFirstname, tLastname, tSlot
    
    'dbQuery = "UPDATE users SET active = 1, slot = " & iSlot & " WHERE LDAPName = 'aaadmin'"
    'dbCall dbQuery, 0
    dbQuery = "SELECT LDAPName, Vorname, Nachname FROM users WHERE active > 0 AND slot = " &iSlot & " ORDER BY Vorname"
    Set lUsers = dbCall(dbQuery, -1)
    iCount = 0
    
    tSlot = "Slot" & iSlot
    Set oSlot = document.GetElementByID(tSlot)
    For Each field in lUsers
        If iCount < 0 Then
            iCount = 0
        End If
        Select Case iCount
            Case 0
                Set NewNode = document.CreateElement("div")
                If field = "aaadmin" Then
                    NewNode.setAttribute "ID", "dummy" & iSlot
                Else
                    NewNode.setAttribute "ID", field
                End If
            Case 1
                NewNode.innerHTML = field
            Case 2
                NewNode.innerHTML = NewNode.innerHTML & " " & field
                oSlot.appendChild(NewNode)
                iCount = -1
        End Select
        iCount = iCount + 1
    Next
End function

function createSlots()
    'fills main
    iSlotCount = getSlotAmount() 'currently returns 5
    iWidth = 72 / iSlotCount
    iWidth = round(iWidth)
    sWidth = "width: " & iWidth & "%;"
    iSlot = 0
    
    'create Slots 1 to n with n = iSlotCount
    while iSlot <= iSlotCount       
        If iSlot > 0 Then
            iSlotSize = getSlotSize(iSlot) 'maximum amount of users in this slot
        End If
        iSlotUsers = getUserInSlot(iSlot)
        iSlotName = getSlotName(iSlot) 'basically returns "slot" & iSlot
        Set NewNode = document.CreateElement("div")
        NewNode.setAttribute "ID", "Slot" & iSlot
        If iSlot = 0 Then
            NewNode.setAttribute "class", "content NoSlot"
        Else
            NewNode.setAttribute "class", "content slot"
            NewNode.setAttribute "style", sWidth
        End If
        slots.appendChild(NewNode) 'add new slot
        
        Set NewChild = document.CreateElement("span")
        NewChild.setAttribute "ID", "UsersIn" & iSlot
        NewChild.innerHTML = iSlotUsers
        If iSlot > 0 Then
            NewChild.innerHTML = NewChild.innerHTML & " / " & iSlotSize
        End If
        NewChild.innerHTML = NewChild.innerHTML & "<br>"
        NewNode.appendChild(NewChild) 'add title to slot
        
        sButtonText = "diesen Pausenslot wählen (Alt + " & iSlot & ")" 'mouseover-text for button
        Set NewChild = document.CreateElement("button")
        NewChild.setAttribute "class", "button"
        NewChild.setAttribute "ID", "btn" & iSlot
        NewChild.setAttribute "accesskey", iSlot
        NewChild.setAttribute "title", sButtonText
        NewChild.setAttribute "disabled" 'changed in another function (tbd)
        NewChild.setAttribute "onClick", "claimSlot(" & iSlot &")"
        NewChild.innerHTML = iSlotName
        NewNode.appendChild(NewChild) 'adds a button to move own account into this slot
        'add users that are already in this slot
        fillSlot(iSlot)
        iSlot = iSlot + 1
    wend
End function
```

Database:

| LDAPName (str) | Vorname (str) | Nachname (str) | active (int) | slot (int) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaadmin | admin | admin | 0 | 0 |
| dummy0 | dummy | dummy | 1 | 0 |
| dummy1 | first | dummy | 1 | 0 |
| dummy2 | second | dummy | 0 | 1 |
| dummy3 | third | dummy | 1 | 2 |
| dummy4 | forth | dummy | 1 | 3 |
| dummy5 | fifth | dummy | 1 | 4 |
| dummy6 | sixth | dummy | 1 | 5 |

What this code does: It generates 6 Slots with IDs 0 to 5, adds a button to each slot to change what slot the own account is in (the buttons code is not included in this post) and loads every user that's active (active > 0) and is in slot iSlot (which is the index of createSlots main-loop).

Problem: This does only add one user each. every slot contains a div with innerHTML = "admin admin". the dummy-accounts dummy0 to dummy6 aren't added at all.

Edit: I just set 2 rows to active = 0 (see above), causing "An exception error occurred" (actually "Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten", translated by Google) when fillSlots is called with iSlot = 1

Comment: What happens if you remove the select case and do what is done in the case's, in the same order?

Comment: each time the loop run's the variable "field" has different content. so at the first time field is the LDAPName, the second time it ist the firstname, the third time it is the lastname of a user. without the cases i would generate a div with id=LDAPName and innerHTML = "LDAPName DAPName", the second time it would be ID= firstname and innerHTML = "Firstname Firstname", the third time ID=Lastname and innerHTML = "Lastname Lastname"

Comment: tried that, without case it does in fact add 3 entries per slot (one entry per LDAPName, Firstname and Lastname), so I can's just loop through my results, I need to find another way...

Comment: @Flakes thanks for your hints, at least I've got another problem now :-D

Comment: @Flakes No, I'm not. I'm just an IT-support. I've learned some coding in school (C# and webdesign) but the switch cases have another reason: I've learned that "if / else if / else if / else" is considered bad behavior so as soon as I figured out to need an if /else if-structure I try to replace it with a switch case.

Comment: And in your dbCall function, it is getting the [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/the-fields-collection?view=sql-server-ver15) of the recordset. Is that what you want, or should you be returning the recordset and then get the field names and values from it?

Comment: @Flakes I just added a third function and the database (every line of the table does currently exist exactly like that in my db; just stipped down unneccessary colums and accounts that aren't returned because active = 0), does this answer your question about my code? And: I tried to return the whole recordset but couldn't make it work. How would I do that? it would probably help a lot.

Comment: @Flakes in this particular scenario, where every slot contains a user, it add's the first found user per slot. while actually using the program that's not the case, by default every user is in slot 0 and the slots 1-5 are empty. Then fillSlot(1) causes an error (german message: Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten, google translated to: An exception error occurred) on the line NewNode.setAttribute "ID", field - just put that error-scenario into my question-post

Comment: I tried to return the whole recordset with "set dbCall = objRecordset". that didn't work but I don't remember the error right now. I guess I'll try to do that again...

Comment: @Flakes there does exist almost no html, everything in this is generated by the code above. I would have to redirect everything into a file instead of the hta-window to provide that (and just don't know how to do that). The only thing that's not generated from this code but is hardcoded to the hta is a div with ID="slots", that's only used once per loop in the line slots.appendChild(NewNode)... I'll stick to the idea to return the whole recordset, that would at least help me to get rid of the switch cases in fillSlot

Comment: Okay. I  did try with div with id= slots, when I got an error on lline 91, which is looking for the slot with id `"Slot" & iSlot` , so I had to add  a bunch of slots with ids Slot0, Slot1,... :). Thats why I thought there are already divs with that ids... Which is the first method you are calling? I will take a look later, its a bit late here.  maybe someone else will come along and clear this in no time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240271/discussion-between-flakes-and-soyaro).

Answer (score 0):

Reworked the code like this:

```
function dbCall(dbQuery, iAmount)
    
    Dim sConnectionString, objConnection, objRecordset, lTemp
    
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & localDB
    objCommand.ActiveConnection = sConnectionString
    
    'dbQuery = dbQuery & ";"
    
    'do DB-Stuff
    'objConnection.open sConnectionString
    'objRecordset.Open dbQuery, objConnection
    objCommand.CommandText = dbQuery
    objCommand.CommandType = 1
    set objRecordset = objCommand.Execute
    Select Case iAmount
        Case -1
            'unbekannte Anzahl, Liste definieren und als ganzes zurückgeben
            set lTemp = objRecordset
            'objRecordset.close
            'objConnection.close
            set dbCall = lTemp
        Case 0
            'kein Rückgabewert - für Update und Insert-Calls
            'objRecordset.close
            'objConnection.close
            dbCall = 0
        Case 1
            'genau ein Rückgabewert - Standardfall
            lTemp = objRecordset.fields(0)
        
            'objRecordset.close
            'objConnection.close
            dbCall = lTemp
    End Select
End function

function fillSlot(iSlot)
    Dim lUsers, oSlot, tid, tFirstname, tLastname, tSlot
    
    dbQuery = "SELECT LDAPName, Vorname, Nachname FROM users WHERE active > 0 AND slot = " &iSlot & " ORDER BY Vorname"
    Set lUsers = dbCall(dbQuery, -1)
    
    tSlot = "Slot" & iSlot
    Set oSlot = document.GetElementByID(tSlot)
    Do While not lUsers.EOF
        Set NewNode = document.CreateElement("div")
        NewNode.setAttribute "ID", lUsers.Fields.Item("LDAPName").Value
        NewNode.innerHTML = lUsers.Fields.Item("Vorname").Value & " " & lUsers.Fields.Item("Nachname").Value
        oSlot.appendChild(NewNode)
        lUsers.moveNext
    Loop
End function
```

Actually I changed one line in dbCall and completely rewrote fillSlot. I have no idea what happened when I tried to do this the last time, this time it worked. every active user get's listed in the slots, no errors if nobody is listed in a slot, this just seems to work as intended.

Comment: explanation: the code in my question did transfer the fields of the first dataset, that's why every user except the first one got discarded. by returning the whole recordset I get all datasets to work with.